# Set scroll position in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm writing an application in wxpython.

The panel I'm working can have something like 1,000 rows, and I want to start the user looking at the middle.

Is there some method I can use to scroll to a specific y coordinate? If my window is 10,000px high, I'd like to set it to start looking at position 5,000px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using a ScrolledWindow, you can use its Scroll method: http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/wxPython/Widgets/wx.ScrolledWindow.html#Scroll

The ScrolledPanel from wx.lib.scrolledpanel also has this method, so it should work too. If you have created a custom widget, you'll need to do all this yourself.